# How to run a custom C# function only when a TransactionScope has committed?

Tags: c#, transactions

I have a TransactionScope that all of my SQL Server connections enlist in. If any of the calls fail, everything rolls back correctly, as expected.

However, I have multiple data stores that need to be updated sometimes in the same call. The second data store does not automatically enlist in the transaction.

I have some ideas on how to stop the other data stores from getting premature data. My first thought was an ExecutionContext-level property that, only when set to a value (true or false for committed or rolled back, for example) would my events that update the other data stores fire off.

However, this seems rather hacky.

Is there a way built into the TransactionScope object to run a function only after the commit has happened? Something along the lines of

```
Transaction.Scope.Current.Enlist(
    onCommit: () => MyCustomSuccessFunction(),
    onRollback: () => MyCustomFailureFunction());
```

Comment: Perhaps you should wrap your call in a helper function that allows you to pass in commit/rollback function references.  I'm not aware of anything "built-in" to ADO.Net, although if you are using a specific abstraction/orm, it might contain something.  Currently this question is too broad to properly answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a decent answer here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149779(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    private class FooEnlistment : IEnlistmentNotification
    {
        private readonly Action _CommitAction;

        private readonly Action _RollbackAction;

        public EventEnlistment(Action onCommit, Action onRollback)
        {
            _CommitAction = onCommit;
            _RollbackAction = onRollback;
        }

        public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
        {
            preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
        }

        public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
        {
            _CommitAction();
            enlistment.Done();
        }

        public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
        {
            _RollbackAction();
            enlistment.Done();
        }

        public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
        {
            enlistment.Done();
        }
    }
```

Then, in the question instead of

```
    Transaction.Scope.Current.Enlist(
        onCommit: () => MyCustomSuccessFunction(),
        onRollback: () => MyCustomFailureFunction());
```

You would do:

```
    var enlistment = new FooEnlistment(MyCustomSuccessFunction, MyCustomFailureFunction);
    Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatile(enlistment, EnlistmentOptions.None);
```